# Date picker automation facing issues

Tags: java, datepicker

I am trying to automate the jQueryUi datepicker, the code for the year navigation is working fine, the month navigation is facing issues. Suppose the date that I want to pick is 20 January 2015, the code which I have written is going to the month of January in the year 2015, but then it is going into the second while loop where it shouldn't.

I debugged the code but still I see that where the second while loop should return false, it is returning true. I don't know why such a thing is happening. Please find the code that I have written for the month navigation below.

```
while (mon != (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText()))
{
    // System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText());
    if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText() != "January")
    {
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ui-datepicker-prev")).click();
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText());
    }

    if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText().equals("January"))
    {
        break;
    }
}

while (mon !=(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText())) 
{
    if (mon != driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText())
    {
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ui-datepicker-next")).click();
        System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText());
    }

    if (mon.equals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText()))
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally after working for sometime on this , got the perfect workaround:-
private static void PickDate(WebDriver driver, String day, String mon, String year) throws Exception {
     while (year != driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-year")).getText())
     {
         if (Integer.parseInt(year) < Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-year")).getText()))
         {
             driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ui-datepicker-prev")).click();
             System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText());
         }
         else if (Integer.parseInt(year) > Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-year")).getText()))
         {
             driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ui-datepicker-next")).click();
         }
         else if(Integer.parseInt(year)== Integer.parseInt(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-year")).getText())){
             break;
         }
     } 
     while (!mon.equals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText()))
     {
//       System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText());

```
     if (!"January".equals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText()))
     {
         driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ui-datepicker-prev")).click();
         System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText());
     }
     if (driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText().equals("January"))
     {
         break;
     }
 }

 while (!mon.equals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText())){

     if (!mon.equals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText()))
     {
         driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.ui-datepicker-next")).click();
         System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText());
     }
     if (mon.equals(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-datepicker-month")).getText()))
     {
         break;
     }
 }
```

//           WebElement dates = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input.hasDatepicker"));
           List columns=driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table.ui-datepicker-calendar>tbody>tr>td>a"));

```
     //comparing the text of cell with today's date and clicking it.
     for (WebElement cell : columns)
     {
        if ((cell.getText()).equals(day))
        {
           cell.click();
           break;
        }
     }



 }
```